# Get array elements that fall into a range without error

Tags: arrays, swift, slice

Is it possible to get elements of the array by slice, if the range goes beyond? for example:

```
var array = [0,1,2,3,4]
print(array[3...100])
```

Is there any way to get [3,4]? I need only the part that falls into the range. For example, in Python, I could make an array [3: 100] and get the elements that fall into this range without errors. Maybe there is an analogue in swift?

Comment: `print(array.filter { 3...100 ~= $0 })`

Comment: `print(array[3...min(100, array.endIndex - 1)])`

Comment: @vacawama this assumes the array has at least 4 items.

Comment: @LeoDabus, that is correct, otherwise *boom*.  BTW, your comment is filtering on the values when the OP is really asking about the indices.

Comment: I’ve already realized that

Answer (score -1):

Because Swift was designed to be safe, so you need to be aware that your code may run into some problem, in swift you can do this?

```
   var bound = 100

   if (array.count < 100) {
      bound = array.count
   }

   if (array.count >= 3) {
      print(array(3...bound))
   }
```

That's the beauty of the language, you shouldn't do something that is error prone without throwing an error.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by clamping your initial range (`3...100`) to the array's indices. However, this doesn't work with `ClosedRanges` (`...`), only `Ranges`.

- You can either convert to a `Range` with `Range(3...100)`, or
- You just change your `ClosedRange` literal to directly be a `Range`: `3..<101`

```
let array = [0,1,2,3,4]
print(array[(3..<101).clamped(to: array.indices)]) // => [3, 4]
```

If you do this often enough, you should make an extension for it:

```
extension Collection {
    subscript<R: RangeExpression>(allowingOutOfBoundsRange rangeExpression: R) -> Self.SubSequence
        where R.Bound == Self.Index, Self.Indices == Range<Self.Index> {
        let range = rangeExpression.relative(to: self)
        let clampedRange = range.clamped(to: self.indices)
        return self[clampedRange]
    }
}
```

Ideally though, you should just avoid trying to index with out of bounds indices in the first place. Range expressions like `3...`, `...3`, etc. could be pretty helpful to mitigate most of the need for something like this.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. You are mixing the elements value with their indices. Seems to me that OP is looking for a simple filter for values in the range from 3 to 100

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm going off of the python notation he provided. `array[3:100]` is a slicing operation in python, not a filtering one.